# String replace not replacing letter as expected

Tags: javascript, function, replace

I'm trying to create a function to replace some letters so I can call the same function in various places. So far this is what I created. Can't make function the return data to main code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    MyFunction("Hello");
    alert(text);
});

function MyFunction(text) {
    var text = text.replace("h","m");
    return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use a different variable name other than `text`.

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Comment: Using `.replace()` in this manner is case-sensitive.

Comment: Pls describe the exact functionality u r getting from this code..

Comment: Please edit the title of this post to match the main question inside. This helps people efficiently find the  questions/answers they are looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function call in the alert or set it to a variable, and then if you want to replace an uppercase `H`, use `H` not `h` in your function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    alert(MyFunction("Hello"));
});

function MyFunction(text) {
  var text = text.replace("H","m");
    return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because there is no small `h` in the word. Instead look for a large `H`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      let text = MyFunction("Hello");
      console.log(text);
});

function MyFunction(t) {
    let text = t.replace("h","m");
    return text
}
```

Or use regex, instead, to ignore the case:
    `t.replace(/h/ig,"m")`

Comment: It does still returns "Hello"

Comment: Uppercase/lowercase

Comment: it is because there is no small h in the word try to use regex instead to ignore the case `t.replace(/h/ig,"m")`

Comment: For those unfamiliar with regex, the  starting `/` wrappers are used to indicate a "regex" expression. the `i` is a flag to ignore case. The `g` (not strictly necessary in the case), indicates to do the search globally in the whole string, instead of stopping at the first occurrence. Regex101.com is great for testing regex expressions, as well as learning how to use them. When writing regex in code, I recommend always testing them out on an online regex tester before proceeding with the rest of your code. I also highly recommend learning regex. It'll come in handy more often than you think.

Answer (score 0):

```
replace("h","m");
```

will replace h with m, you want

```
replace("H","m");
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore case sensitivity

```
function MyFunction (text) {
    return text.replace(/h/i, "m");
}
```